# Unable to find and install Analysis Bootstrapper plugin in SonarQube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, fxcop, fxcopcmd

I am trying to enable to FXcop rules in sonar and analyze the code . But I am getting the below error in

> ERROR: Caused by: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly" must be set
>   and the pro ject must have been built to execute FxCop rules. This
>   property can be automatic ally set by the Analysis Bootstrapper for
>   Visual Studio Projects plugin, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg. If you wish to skip the analysis of
>   not built pr ojects, set the property
>   "sonar.visualstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".

Console log  states that this property will be automatically set by [Analysis Bootstrapper for Visual Studio plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/Analysis+Bootstrapper+for+Visual+Studio+Projects+Plugin) . But I am unable to find and install this plugin in sonar.

I also tried setting up the below properties in sonar . But still getting the same error

```
sonar.cs.fxcop.fxCopCmdPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0\FxCopCmd.exe
sonar.fxcop.installDirector=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Fxcop 10.0
```

Why the Analysis Bootstrapper plugin is not coming in the sonar plugins area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing this issue, Please follow the below steps

1. Download the package from the below URL

   [Analysis Bootstrapper Pluggin for Visual Studio](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.visualstudio/sonar-visual-studio-plugin/1.2)
2. Copy the **sonar-visual-studio-plugin-1.2.jar** file to your Sonar \extensions\plugins folder
3. Restart the server and you will see the plugin in installed plugin section

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs if you are launching your commands from a prompt which is not a "Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2013 or higher" (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).